# how to read a file (.txt) in a JTextArea without using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I would like to know how I read a file (*.txt*) in a `JTextArea` without using `JFileChooser`?
I would like to know if there is any other way to write the code on the body of program to display it on ``` JTextArea`` without using ```JFileChooser`?

Comment: How would you choose the file??

Comment: i have thought in that but there is a way to write a in a body of a program ?

Comment: Yes, use `FileReader` class to read the file and store the data into string then use `setText()` method to add text into `TextArea`

Comment: `JFileChooser` is not used for reading files. `FileReader` and all subtypes are used for reading files.

Comment: thanks Vighanesh Gursale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<Filename>"));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
     txtArea.append(line);
}
in.close(

);
```

Comment: Better solution would be just to use [`txtArea.read(in, null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)